# Detect hit to back history in angular

Tags: angularjs, controller, browser-history

I did this below to detect back button hit to previous page, but the detection is working fine, my headache is that the app run functions variable `$rootScope.UseInController` don't pass the data once to controller.
Here is the script.

```
  App.run(function($rootScope, $location, $route, $localStorage){



$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    // Check if you've been here before.  
    $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path(); 

});

});
$rootScope.$watch(
    function() { 
        return $location.path(); 
    },
    function(newLocation, oldLocation){
         if($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
            $rootScope.backClicked = true;
        }
    },true);
})
```

Please help me out....

Answer (score 0):

This is what i finally does and make it worked perfectly, i delay my controller a bit.

```
$timeout(function(){..}, 5);
```